# how to set the max. length of text in edittext control

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know how can I set maximum length of text in an edittext control in android. I want the edittext to be able to handle large amount of text. How can I accomplish this.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editEntryView.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner in android. How much text can fit in edittext using the above code.

Comment: In this case you can fit the size of your LenghtFilter(8), change 8 for the number you want!

Answer (score 3):

In the xml declaration of the edittext you can add the atribute

```
android:maxLength="100" // or the size that you want
```

Comment: much more elegant than blessenm's functional solution